# Oauth2.0 setup for SAP Hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, sap-cloud-platform

I'm exploring hybris sales cloud trial version. I want to test oauth2 using postman, I don't know if this is the right way but I created a client application in SAP Cloud Platform cockpit by going to ***{subaccount} | Security | Oauth | Clients***. What do I put in **Subscription**? And in postman, what should I put as the scope?

Answer (score 3):

Click on Authorization tab and Click on get "New Access Token" button and configure the Oauth client as configured in hybris

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First create **OAuthClientDetails**, for this, you can use Impex to create, below is one example

```
INSERT_UPDATE OAuthClientDetails;clientId[unique=true];resourceIds;scope;authorizedGrantTypes                ;authorities                                                                 ;clientSecret;registeredRedirectUri
                            ;qwe                  ;hybris     ;basic;implicit,client_credentials,password;ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT,ROLE_CLIENT,ROLE_CUSTOMERMANAGERGROUP,ROLE_CUSTOMERGROUP;secret;
```

This will create one OauthClientDetails, We have given authorization also, to access all the different types.

Next, go to Postman and do configuration as below

grant type : Password Credentials

Access Token URL : https://localhost:9002/authorizationserver/oauth/token

Username : admin

Password: nimda

Client ID: create your client details

Client secret : secret/password

scope: basic

Client Authentication: send as basic Auth header

[image]